# flex: referencing class variables

Tags: apache-flex, class-design

I have a bunch of variables in a class. There are situations when I want to set then to null/ "temp" etc as per a well defined logic. The challenge is to list out the variables at multiple places- tedious and error-prone.

classname.speed=NaN

classname.speedtype="not_set"

classname.distance=NaN

classname.distancetype="not_set"

Ideally, would prefer a way to refer to these variables programatically and set something like
"for all class variables- if variable ends in type, set as "not_set"; for other variables set as NaN

How can I achieve this? Any pointers will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach would be just write function to clear them all.
If you want something more automatic, it will requre efforts - look at [introspection api](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=usingas_8.html). Basically, you call `describeType` on your class and it returns XML description. All variables will be listed there, along with other info. Then you can parse returned XML and set all variables to needed value, accessing them dynamically with square bracket syntax:

```
var myClass:MyClass = new MyClass();
myClass["varName"] = "new value";
```

Answer (score 0):

It can  be achieved through **Inheritance** i.e. *implementing* **interface** or *extending* **class** 
which contains common fields

```
public class MyClass
{
    public a:String = null;
    public b:String = null;

    public function MyClass()
    {
    }

}
```

which contains common var and Child Class could be

```
public class MyClassChild extends MyClass
{
    public var c:String = null;
    public function MyClassChild()
    {
        super();
        this.a ="";
        this.b ="";
    }

}
```

and you can  cast or use for each loop to set values

```
var temp:MyClassChild  = new MyClassChild ();

MyClass(temp).a = "Hello World";
```

Hopes that helps